# Can't find file in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting

In my website I'm trying to implement [friendly URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine). I have an `index.php` file and a `.htaccess` file in my hosting's public folder. I'm using the following code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/$ ../Feed/Article.php?id=$1
```

Therefore, if anyone enters `www.example.com/article/15/`, it loads the `Article.php` passing the `15` value through GET.

But the problem is that the `Article.php` file is outside the public folder (hence the `../`) and Apache doesn't find it.

Can anyone help me?

Note: I **don't** have access to the `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't rewrite to a filesystem path but a URI. so if `Article.php` is at `http://example.com/Article.php` your rewrite rule would look like:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/$ http://example.com/Article.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Probably better off stripping the `http://example.com` out of that rewrite.

Comment: Oh, ok I understand. But that forces me to save all the files inside the public folder, right? Isn't it that *very* insecure?

Comment: You can put it in another subdirectory and forbid access to it. But I don't see why it should be a security issue if users can access the script directly?